# Running PHP from Command Line Interface

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-interface

I am trying to complete the upgrade tutorial for Kayako SupportSuite (a ticket/knowledge based system)

It states the following:-
Execute the script by running php /cli/moveattachments.php.

Can anyone explain how I run this command from the command line? (I've never had to do it before)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Have you researched this yourself yet? Tried anything?

Comment: Sorry - my fault it was badly worded. I realise now I need to use SSH, I am just in the process of installing the software now. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type:

```
php /cli/moveattachments.php
```

(adjusting the path to match wherever you put the file)

Then press the return key.

Comment: Definitely recommend not starting with the `/`

Comment: @Tom: Creating a cli directory off the root would be an *odd* thing to do, and not something I'd recommend, but it is possible that an earlier part of the instructions said to do that. I did say to adjust the path to wherever the file actually was.

Comment: a cursory google shows the command is allegedly [as typed in the question](http://wiki.kayako.com/display/DOCS/Importing+your+data+from+Kayako+3+to+Kayako+4)

Comment: Can I just do the following cron command to run this in CPanel 11?
0 0 * * * php /cli/moveattachments.php

Answer (score 1):

assuming you're on windows, click the window-button and 'R' and type 'CMD', you're then in a DOS prompt. There you can type your PHP command (php /cli/moveattachments.php)